# Rebinding M-q in `define-minor-mode`

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

I'm trying to define a minor mode that rebinds `M-q` to a modified version of `fill-paragraph`. What I've written so far:

```lisp
(defun myfun ()
  (message "myfun called"))
(define-minor-mode mymode
  "Test for minor mode keymap."
  :lighter " MM"
  :keymap '(([M-q] . myfun)))
```

doesn't work, as `M-q` is still bound to `fill-paragraph` when `mymode` is active. Can anyone spot the issue with my code and tell me how to rebind that key properly?

Comment: Please move the solution to an answer - remove it from the question. (You can accept your own answer.)

Comment: @Drew Done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrast `M-f1` for a function key with `?\M-f` for a character. You've bound `myfun` to `[M-q]` which means the one-key sequence where the key is the function key called `q` (which does not exist) with the modifier whose prefix is `M` (which is meta). Instead of referencing a function key `q`, you need to reference the character `q`. You can write this `[?\M-q]`, or in string notation `"?\M-q"`. You can also use the ESC prefix (written `\e` as a character) instead of the meta modifier: `"\eq"` or `[?\e \q]`.

(Do not use `[escape q]`, because that would override the default redirection of the `escape` function key to the escape character `?\e`, and so pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>*key*</kbd> would no longer be equivalent to <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>*key*</kbd>.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed `[M-q]` to `[?\M-q]`, and now the function the rebound keys work. There was another problem (the key must be bound to a command, not a function), but that was easier to fix. Will update the question and add the working version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider calling `(define-key mymode-map [remap fill-paragraph] #'myfun)` from `mymode-hook` rather than defining it in the minor mode.

```
(defun remap-fill-paragraph ()
  (define-key mymode-map [remap fill-paragraph] #'myfun))

(add-hook 'mymode-hook #'remap-fill-paragraph)
```

This means you don't have to remember to change the minor-mode mapping if you ever change the default mapping for `fill-paragraph`.

Unfortunately (based on a single quick test) it seems that the expansion of the `define-minor-mode` Lisp macro is not smart enough to handle a `[remap ...]` within the `:keymap` form, hence the need to use the more verbose approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code above:

1. The code was bound to the non-existing `q` function key (see Gilles' answer).
2. In order to be added to a keymap, functions must be commands (i.e. interactive).

The following code works and solves both problems:

```lisp
(defun myfun ()
  (interactive)
  (message "myfun called"))
(define-minor-mode mymode
  "Test for minor mode keymap."
  :lighter " MM"
  :keymap '([?\M-q] . myfun))
```